# Why does the tarball directory structure disappear when I use Perl's Archive::Tar?

Tags: perl, tar, archive-tar

I'm using a Perl script to modify some files inside a .tar, and the directory structure inside the resulting .tar disappears.
Eliminating more and more code I've come as far as all that's required to reproduce this is

```
my $data_tar = Archive::Tar->new('data.tar');
$data_tar->write('modified_data.tar');
```

Both .tar-files have all the files, however the indication of what directories the files and subdirectories were located in are lost.

I've looked through the docs and src for [Archive::Tar](http://cpansearch.perl.org/perldoc/Archive::Tar) but I really don't understand what's going on.

I'm using perl 5.10.0 on win32, tar 1.12 and Archive::Tar 1.54.
I examined the .tar-files in an editor and the data.tar contains dir/ and dir/file.txt, but in the modified_data.tar they show up as dir and file.txt so my original tar seems ok.

Anyone of you that have seen this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C:\Temp> perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.1 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

```
C:\Temp> perl -MArchive::Tar -e "print $Archive::Tar::VERSION"
1.52
```

Cannot replicate using `data.tar` created with:

```
C:\Temp> tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.21
```

As @~quack notes, the [docs state](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Archive::Tar):

> Note that GNU tar earlier than version 1.14 does not cope well with the POSIX header prefix. If you use such a version, consider setting the [`$Archive::Tar::DO_NOT_USE_PREFIX`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Archive::Tar#%24Archive::Tar::DO_NOT_USE_PREFIX) variable to `true`.

Comment: from the POD (regarding GNU tar versions): "Note that GNU tar earlier than version 1.14 does not cope well with
the POSIX header prefix. If you use such a version, consider setting the $Archive::Tar::DO_NOT_USE_PREFIX variable to true."

Comment: @~quack: I didn't really know what a posix header was so I guess I skipped past that part. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @quack: I'm surprised you didn't just make that an answer, since it seems to be the problem being run into.

Comment: @R. Bemrose I think @~quack realized that because I originally provided the GNU tar version in my post and was nice about it.

Comment: @R. Bemrose didn't know that was the answer at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script but could not reproduce the problem (on FreeBSD using Perl 5.10).